# OpenGL ES 2.0 square looks like rectangle

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I've finally got some geometry drawing with OpenGL ES 2.0 on android and when I'm drawing a square it ends up looking like a rectangle.

In 3D you calculate an aspect ratio for the projection matrix but I'm only doing 2D drawing so is there something I need to setup to not have 'stretched' geometry?

Thanks

Rectangle:

```
public Rectangle(float width, float height) {

    _width = width;
    _height = height;

    float halfWidth = _width * 0.5f;
    float halfHeight = _height * 0.5f;

    float[] vertices = new float[] {
        -halfWidth, halfHeight, 0.0f,      0.0f, 0.0f,
        -halfWidth, -halfHeight, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f,
        halfWidth, -halfHeight, 0.0f,      1.0f, 1.0f,
        halfWidth, halfHeight, 0.0f,       1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    _vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asFloatBuffer();
    _vertexBuffer.put(vertices).position(0);

    short[] indices = new short[] {
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3
    };

    _indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asShortBuffer();
    _indexBuffer.put(indices).position(0);
}

public void draw(Shader shader, Vector2 pos, Texture2D texture)
{
    int shaderId = shader.getProgramId();

    int vertexPosId = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderId, "vPosition");
    int texCoordId = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderId, "vTexCoord");
    int textureLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderId, "texture");
    int positionId = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderId, "mPosition");

    _vertexBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexPosId, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, _vertexBuffer);

    _vertexBuffer.position(3);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordId, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, _vertexBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosId);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordId);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture.bind();

    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureLoc, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform2fv(positionId, 1, pos.getArray(), 0);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosId);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoordId);
}
```

GLRenderer:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {

    _shader = Shader.createShaderProgram(Shader.VERT_2D_TEX, Shader.FRAG_TEX);

    _rect = new Rectangle(1.0f, 1.0f);

    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, _width, _height);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    _rect.draw(_shader, _pos, _texture);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
public static final String VERT_2D_TEX =
                "uniform vec3 mPosition;" +
                "attribute vec3 vPosition;" +
                "attribute vec2 vTexCoord;" +
                "varying vec2 uv;" +
                "void main()" +
                "{" +
                "  uv = vTexCoord;" +
                "  gl_Position = vec4(mPosition + vPosition, 1.0);" +
                "}";
```

Comment: You've probably made some sort of mistake. If only we could see the code you'd used we might have been able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aspect has nothing to do with 3D vs 2D. Currently, you do not use any trasnformation matrices, but just translate your vertices by adding some position vector. Since you use 1 as the w component, your clip space is indentical to the normalized device space. So, the square [-1,1]x[-1,1] will be mapped to your window. If your window is not square, a square in your input coordinates will end up as a rectangle. You should correct for the aspect in the vertex transfrom stage. Typically, one is using some kind of orthogonal projection matrix which is correcting for the aspect. But a full blown matrix is not required here. All you need to do is forward the aspect as a uniform to the vertex shader and use it to scale along x (or y).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/) is a great tutorial on getting started with OpenGL ES 2.0 and Android.  Read the explanation on matrices and make note of how the Model, View, and Projection matrices are being used in the vertex shader.